# How to display verbatim inline r code with backticks using Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

By doubling the backticks in Markdown, it is easy to render some text in code style including the backticks, such as: `` `r 2+2` ``.
But how to do that with *RMarkdown* ? By the same way we can display `` `t 2+2` ``, but replacing `t` with `r` executes the R code `2+2`.

The only way I have found so far is:

```
<p><code  class="r">`</code><code class="r">r 2+2`</code></p>
```

Not very convenient. Maybe I should define a new css for doing that more conveniently ?

Comment: There's no escape operation (typically done with "\" in R) in RMarkdown?

Comment: @DWin I don't see what you have in mind.

Comment: @agstudy This is not R HTML (I have never used that by the way). HTML is allowed in RMarkdown. Indeed, I'd like to have a solution without HTML (but I'd like to get the r style in addition).

Comment: If you want to protect a back-tick from being parsed as a backtick in R, you can just escape it: `strange.name <- 'abc\\\`def'`: `nchar(strange.name)
[1] 8`  (It even looks like it survived the SO version of Markdown except for the fact that I used _two_ backslashes at the console and only one was showing up in this comment until I added a third one.)

Comment: @DWin I'm under the impression you have never used Rmarkdown. When doing `r 2+2` in Rmarkown between backticks, one gets 4 in the output. I'm afraid your comment has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: Your impression is correct, but I do not think your demonstration proves there is no escape sequence in Markdown. That was my question.

Comment: @Dwin Following your suggestion, this works : `r cat(\\`r 2+2 \\`)` (between backticks) Maybe this is what you meant...

Comment: No sorry that doesn't work...

Comment: I dont suppose that `\`2+2\`` does what you want?  It won't specifically be highlighted for R, but it will be set in monospace font ... oh, no, I see you want the backticks included verbatim ...

Comment: @BenBolker Yes. I have updated the title, I hope it is clearer now ("verbatim" is the appropriate word, thank you)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here is a trick that I use. First, note `\x60` is `` ` ``:

```
> cat('\x60', '\n')
`
```

Then you write

```
`r '\x60r foo+bar\x60'`
```

which will give you `` `r foo+bar` `` in the markdown output, but that will become `r foo+bar` in the HTML output, so you need to protect the backticks in markdown, using two (or more) backticks. Then you end up with this hairball:

```
`` `r '\x60r foo+bar\x60'` ``
```

Your own solution is good, but I'd just define

````
rinline <- function(code) {
  sprintf('``` `r %s` ```', code)
}
````

Also see [this post](https://yihui.name/en/2017/11/knitr-verbatim-code-chunk/) for another trick.

Comment: Nice. I'll use `rinline <- function(code) {
  sprintf('<code  class="r">``` \`r %s\` ```</code>', code)
}
`

Answer (score 5):

To anyone looking at this now, you may want to check out the more recent solution here:
[embed Rmarkdown without knitr evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459166/embed-rmarkdown-with-rmarkdown-without-knitr-evaluation)

Essentially you can do:

```
Some R code inline : `r knitr::inline_expr("2+2")`
```

I'm guessing that the functionality describe above has been added to knitr directly but it saves us defining the function ourselves.

Comment: Wow, this is nice! Especially if you had already loaded `knitr` in the document's session, you can skip `knitr::`

Comment: Nice. I have needed extra single marks around the double quote-marks: knitr::inline_expr(**'**"2+2"**'**), for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

The solution of [Yihui Xie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui-xie) was not displaying the enclosing quotations in the inserted code when rendering a README.md file for a Github repository.
In that case I used html code:

```
<code>&grave;r foo(x)&grave;</code>
```

Which displays `` `r foo(x)` `` inline.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. It works nicely in xaringan slides.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a satisfactory finding. First define the function

````
rinline <- function(code){
  html <- '<code  class="r">``` `r CODE` ```</code>'
  sub("CODE", code, html)
}
````

in an invisible chunk. Then you can show `` `r 2+2` `` by typing:

```
Some R code inline : `r rinline("2+2")` - nice
```

Answer (score 4):

I just learnt about the `results='asis'` option.
So, yet another way; for fun and learning :-)

````
```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
cat("`` `r 2+2` ``")
```
````

Comment: This isn't an in-line solution, which is what the question asked for, as it uses the display environment.