# The double dollar signs `$$` can not show in the markdown code block in gitbook

Tags: markdown, gitbook

I am using gitbook with markdown to write my website. And I want to show a piece of latex codes as following.

````
```
$$
x^2 + y^2 =1 
$$
```
````

But the double dollar signs `$$` disappear on the output html file, just like following

```
x^2 + y^2 = 1
```

So how to solve such a problem. Thanks very much.

Comment: Shot in the dark as I don't use gitbook, can you escape them? `\$\$`

Comment: It can not work, I had tried it.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24840878/5785085

Comment: I tried your sample markdown in a GitBook (from GitHub) project of my own and there were no issues rendering the dollar signs.

Comment: which version of gitbook do you use? @AdamJLimbert

Comment: @HuayiWei : C:\WINDOWS\system32>gitbook -V
CLI version: 2.3.2
GitBook version: 3.2.3