# code chunk following verbatim inline code breaks slide separator

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan, verbatim, remarkjs

In a xaringan presentation I want to show how to put R Code in an R Markdown document. Which leads me to the dangerous waters of verbatim R Markdown in an xaringan (R Markdown) document.

Displaying verbatim inline code works as long as there is no R code chunk on a later slide. If there is a code chunk later on, all slide separation following the verbatim inline code break. They are displayed as horizontal lines. If I remove the code chunk and leave everything else untouched, the slide separation works again properly.

I read #7 in the [knitr FAQ](https://yihui.name/knitr/faq/) and the mentioned [blog post](https://yihui.name/en/2017/11/knitr-verbatim-code-chunk/) as well as stuff on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409172/how-to-display-verbatim-inline-r-code-with-backticks-using-rmarkdown) and [R Views](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/12/04/how-to-show-r-inline-code-blocks-in-r-markdown/). I have no idea what confuses xaringan.

Content of `test_verbatim.Rmd` document:

````r
---
title: "Verbatim Inline Code"
output: xaringan::moon_reader
---
# Before

empty

---
# Current

This will show a verbatim inline R expression `` `r
1+1` `` in the output.

---
# After

An R Code Chunk breaks the slide separator. Without the chunk, slide separation works. Even an inline R expression is okay.

```{r}
1 + 1
```

---
````

I want separate slides (`Before`, `Current` & `After`) with verbatim R Markdown and  R code chunks but get horizontal lines on the slide `Current` instead of slide separation.

Comment: This is reproducible to me, and sounds like a bug of remark.js: https://github.com/gnab/remark

Comment: Thanks a lot for reproducing! I just looked at xaringan and obviously looked to short. Code fenced by more than one backtick (e.g. using ' instead backtick here 'code') in a line (without newlines) throws remark.js off. So the same bug occurs if one writes ''code'' or '' 'code' ''.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue but I don't understand how to solve it (quite new in the xaringan !): how did you finally manage? thanks!

Comment: I didn't manage at all. I think in one case I included a picture of verbatim markdown

Comment: Have you tried escaping the verbatim backticks with: \\` ?