# How to render backticks in HTML inside a code chunk in rmarkdown?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr, backticks

In a .rmd file (output type = html document), I'm trying to render a HTML string containing a backtick (``) in a `r` code block, like in the following example:

````
```{r}
htmltools::HTML('<b>LEFT`RIGHT</b>')
```
````

When I try to knit this, I get the following output:
[image: The HTML string is not rendered correctly]

Instead, I want to display **LEFT`RIGHT**. How do I do it?

I am aware that in this simple case I could just include the HTML in the .rmd instead of passing it to `htmltools::HTML` inside a code block, but for my actual use case, the HTML is inside a parameter, i.e. instead of ``` HTML('<b>LEFT``RIGHT</b>') ``` I have the parameter `params$query`, which i pass to the .rmd file via `rmarkdown::render`. Therefore it has to be included in a r code block to be parsed.

Comment: Try with replacing the backtick by its HTML entity `&grave;`, i.e. `htmltools::HTML('<b>LEFT&grave;RIGHT</b>')`. See [How to display verbatim inline r code with backticks using Rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409172/how-to-display-verbatim-inline-r-code-with-backticks-using-rmarkdown)

Comment: @stefan, this works. Thanks a lot! If you would be willing to reply I could accept your answer. I had seen that question but `&grave;` is only mentioned in one of the bottom answers so I missed it.

Comment: Great. I would feel bad about posting as an answer as I simply picked it from the linked post. Personally I would therefore call it a duplicate even if not a perfect one. Maybe someone else has an opinion on that. (: